# How do I prevent the loss of data from a pivot table after updating the source sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was tasked with creating a report on sales by each employee, sorted by clients and months. I quickly figured out that the quickest way to do it was via a Pivot Table - and it did fulfill this task quickly. However, the data on which the table is based is imported from another worksheet (which in turn gets it from a database), and every day it shows only the last 90 days of data. I was told to make the report retain that data and add to it. Is there a way to do it without creating additional sheets?

Comment: Your description is quite vague. How does your sheet looks like? Where do you want to store the data? You cold use app script to automatically save the data.

Comment: @PySeeker I'd like to store the data, if at all possible, in the report sheet. The data from which a report is made consists of a list of clients, the salesmen that work with them, date of transaction, gain, cost and profit, as well as other data points not used in the report. While I could use GAS to do it, I wanted to know if there were easier solutions, something already built in that I couldn't ding in my search - Pivot table looked like an easy solution, especially with the easy date grouping Google Sheets provided.

Comment: you need script that will archive given range on daily basis

Comment: Your report requires to represent more than the last 90 days of data. How much exactly? The whole historical data?

Comment: @player0 That's what I ended up doing. Thank you